# C++ string literals

Tags: c++

why this code compiles?

```
std::string a = "test"
"a";
```

I know that " is ignored inside a string if \ is missing and this:

```
std::string a = "test""a";
```

will be the same as "testa" but why it compiles when I have space/tab/end of line inside it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whitespace ("space/tab/end of line", as you put it) between adjacent string literals is also ignored.

Since you want to know if this is standard, the C++ standard says:

**2.1[lex.phases]/3**

> The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens (2.4) and sequences of white-space characters

**2.1[lex.phases]/6**

> Adjacent ordinary string literal tokens are concatenated.

And *white-space characters* are defined in **2.4[lex.pptoken]/2** as

> space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed

Also, the example of such concatenation, provided in **2.13.4[lex.string]/3** involves space:

```
[Example:
"\xA" "B"
contains the two characters ’\xA’ and ’B’ after concatenation
```

which shows that the meaning of "adjacent tokens" in this case includes "separated by space", and therefore, "separated by a sequence of white-space characters", which includes new-line as well.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you didn't prove that the meaning of "adjacent" doesn't care about newlines. :P

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I could quote the definition of white space from 2.4/2 (*"comments, or white-space characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), or both"*), meaning that if it doesn't care about space, it doesn't care about newline either.

Comment: @Cubbi: Yep, you could! I think that that would then fully answer the question. I +1'd in anticipation of that.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal The statement he quoted from 2.1[lex.phases]/6 refers
to adjacent tokens, not text.  Since white space (including new lines)
is never part of a token.  This is general in C++: you can have
comments, newlines, and macros and preprocessor declarations which don't
expand to anything between tokens, and the tokens are still adjacent.
(It's even quite common to do so, e.g. when generating version number
strings and such from a -D compiler option, or conditionally including
text in the string.)

Comment: @James: Right, but until the last edit, he hadn't defined "whitespace". Now he has, and all is good. Please note that I never disagreed with his answer or with what he is saying (I already know that what you are saying is correct); I just felt that the answer itself could have been improved.

Answer (score 4):

Because the C++ grammar doesn't care about newlines, tabs or whitespace between tokens (as far as possible).

This is valid in much the same way that:

```
int a = 3 +
        5 +
        9;
```

is valid.

(Of course you often need *some* whitespace between tokens to set them apart, e.g. `int a;` rather than `inta;`. But as long as the distinction isn't required, the whitespace does not matter, e.g. `3 + 5` or `3+5`.)

Comment: The correct analogy would be: int a = 3 4 5; and this will not work

Comment: @Felics: No, your analogy is broken because literal concatenation is only specified for _string_ literals. The point is about newlines, and within that context the above example is accurate.

Comment: You didn't specified that the grammar doesn't care for the newlines, spaces, tabs only for strings, so my analogy is correct from this point of view.

Comment: @Felics: That's because it's not true "only for strings". It's true in general. String literals and integer literals alike can be spread over lines -- this is my answer. That integer literals can't then be concatenated like string literals can is utterly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

It's by design so you can have

```
std::string a = "really"
                "long"
                "string literals"
                "spread over multiple lines";
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is smart enough to optimize this for you.

C++ ignores end of lines in statements - the semicolon determines when the statement is complete.

Comment: I want to know if this is standard(from C++ standard) behavior or not.

Comment: No, it's not an optimisation. It's an explicit language feature.

Comment: @Felics: Yes. It's part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

White space is ignored - the semicolon ends your line.